# Do I need to separate all the eggs if a recipe needs more yolks than whole eggs?

Tags: eggs

I am going to make lemon bars except I am going to use oranges instead, so I was reading the recipe for lemon bars.

The recipe calls for 2 large eggs and 1 large egg yolk separated, then in the instructions it says to beat eggs and egg yolks together in a bowl.

Wouldn't it be okay to just leave them as whole eggs if they are going to be mixed together anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Your recipe calls for both whole eggs and egg yolks. (Presumably, it needs the extra fat from an additional egg yolk without the liquid/protein contribution of an additional egg white.)

Since the goal in this recipe is just to have 2 whites and 3 yolks in the mixture, there is no reason to separate the first two eggs. So you will only need to separate one egg to get that extra yolk.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on why they are separated, if one is going to be cooked more or if you need to fluff up the whites and what not. Another reason is how you want the yolk or white to combine with whats being mixed. The yolk and whites have obvious difference in consistency and flavour so this can make a difference in the end product of the dish if you use the whole egg at once. You can probably get away with putting it all in at once assuming theres no cooking or whisking difference but the texture will be off from the the intended in the recipe so its better to just separate it unless you have experience and knowledge that its better whole. Also another reasoning for adding them separately could be to avoid clumping in which case you'll be causing yourself more work if you put it in all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> It calls for 2 large eggs, 1 large egg yolk, and says to beat eggs and
>   egg yolks together in a bowl.

I am not reading that as the 2 large eggs need to be separated.

Comment: You are actually correct! I don't know why I assumed they were all to be separated. I can't believe I didn't read it that way. Embarrassing.